# What is the right way to share subproject functionality with dependencies?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, spring-boot-starter

I'm working on a multimodule gradle (kts) project. Each module is a spring boot kotlin app, that provides Elasticsearch requests and responses, for example:

```
project
- module core
- module a
- module b
- module c
- module d
```

First three modules use the same common functionality from the lib:
`implementation("co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.12.1")`. Basically, I need to create a client that could be resued by my project modules.

The problem is that I can't create my own spring boot starter or push it to any artifactory. I'd like to create another module (e.g. `module e`) and import it as an implementation at other modules.

I've created that module, and successfully attached it to other dependant modules.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

dependencies {

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // Starter
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")

    // Elasticsearch
    implementation("co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.12.1")
    implementation("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-geo:8.12.1")
    implementation("jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1")

    // Jackson
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.15.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.3")

    // Importing common pojos
    implementation(project(":core"))

    // Logging
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:3.0.5")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
}

tasks {

    withType<Wrapper> {
        version = "8.4"
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    jar {
        enabled = true
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

But there is one slight problem with it. Elasticsearch dependency models are unreachable from other modules.
I don't need to export all available dependencies, but is there any way to export only those for elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elasticsearch dependency models are unreachable from other modules. I don't need to export all available dependencies, but is there any way to export only those for elasticsearch?

The Kotlin (or Java library) plugin makes available an additional configuration `api` for use when writing a library module. This acts the same as the `implementation` configuration, except that `api` dependencies are also made available to consumers of the library.

So if in Module E's `build.gradle.kts` file you write:

```
dependencies {
    api("co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:8.12.1")
}
```

Then any projects using Module E as a dependency will be able to use classes included in the `elasticsearch-java` JAR in addition to classes in Module E.

Comment: Thanks! THat't the thing I needed)

Answer (score 0):

You can try allprojects {} script block in your gradle for the dependencies.

[gradle allprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:allprojects(groovy.lang.Closure))

[gradle multiproject builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html)